# CRM charts XML, changing x-axis values

Tags: xml, charts, dynamics-crm

I am trying to arrange CRM chart x-axis values with custom intervals.

I want it be like 0-5-10-25 etc., not all the values.

[image: CRM 2015 chart]

As you see, it shows all the values. Can you help?

I tried  `<LabelStyle Format="#,;-#,;0 K" .../>` but not working!

Comment: I've tried to do this and found no solution. I think that Microsoft is telling us that you never need to change the X-axis labels :/

Comment: You say that they knew the best for us :)